# In React js Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at shouldFilterFiber at mountFiberRecursively

Tags: reactjs

I am using s josn file to map and create new Polylines on a leaflet map, but I am getting this error. the app works fine and all the polyline shows on map but I get this error( Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at shouldFilterFiber at mountFiberRecursively) in console of browser!
Here is my code:

```
export default class MapLeaflet extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  lat: 61.7,
  lng: 26.1,
  zoom: 6,
}
}

render() {
const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
return (
  <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {coordinates.features.map((element) => (
      <Polyline
        key={element.properties.OBJECTID}
        color="lime"
        positions={element.geometry.coordinates}
      />
    ))}
  </Map>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For people who are looking for an answer: the problem was because the array that I was trying to map was too big it was returning like 6000 polyline elements. The solution was to divide the array into 3 part of 2000 and then map them separately. I am not sure if it is the right way to do it but it solved my problem. Hope that it help someone.